# Validate an XML against a specific XSD schema

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xml-validation

I have a webservice that gets specific XML which does not have a schema specified in the file itself.
I do have XSD schemas in my project which will be used to test the obtained XML files against them.

The problem is that whatever I do the validator seems to accept the files even when they aren't valid.

The code I'm using is this (some parts omitted to make it easier):

```
var schemaReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlSchemeInput));
var xmlSchema = XmlSchema.Read(schemaReader, ValidationHandler);

var xmlReaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
xmlReaderSettings.Schemas.Add(xmlSchema);
xmlReaderSettings.ValidationEventHandler += ValidationHandler;
xmlReaderSettings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
xmlReaderSettings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessIdentityConstraints;
xmlReaderSettings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
xmlReaderSettings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;

using(var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlInput), xmlReaderSettings))
{
    while (xmlReader.Read()) { }
}

// return if the xml is valid or not
```

I've found several solutions with an inline specified schema which work great, but with a schema specified like this (which I assume should work) I can't seem to find any.

Am I doing something wrong? Or am I just wrong in assuming this is how it should work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

```
xmlReaderSettings.Schemas.Compile()
```

after

```
xmlReaderSettings.Schemas.Add(xmlSchema);
```

worked for me in that situation.